# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string' styleid in C#

Tags: c#

I wanted to compare the `int[] StyleIds` to `string S_StyleId`.
but I dont know how to do it..

```
var cs = optionalEquipments.FirstOrDefault(
               d => d.StyleIds.Any(s=>s.ToString == c.S_StyleId);
```

I wanted to get and compare the styleId

Comment: What does variable `c` contain?

Comment: How can you write s.ToString? Replace with s.ToString().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ToString is a method,

You need to change

```
Any(s=>s.ToString == c.S_StyleId);
```

into

```
Any(s=>s.ToString() == c.S_StyleId);
```